# jQuery-ui slider animation when setting value programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, settimeout

I'm using a [jQuery-ui slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) and some buttons for a quick selection of a little set of values.

When the user clicks one of these buttons, the slider is set to the corresponding value through the `.slider` method:

```
$("#mySlider").slider("value", myValue);
```

This works fine, but I'd like to see the sliding animation. I tried with

```
$("#mySlider").slider({value:myValue, animate:true})
```

but it doesn't work as expected, since the animation is only enabled when, later, the user clicks on the slider bar.

Should I write a function using `setTimeout` to achieve what I want or is there a higher-level way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: please provide us with a sample on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle illustrating a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/exXLV/8/

The Trick seems to be to create a slider and set it's `animate` option to `true`, `slow` ,etc. and after that you should set the value of the slider via `$("#slider").slider('value', 150);`

Notice the difference between using the `.slider('value', 150)` syntax ("the value" function) and using the `.slider({value:myValue, animate:true})` syntax ("the option" function).

HTML:

```
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>

<div id="slider"></div>

<p>Your slider has a value of <span id="slider-value"></span></p>

<button type="button">Set to 150</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#slider").slider(
{
            value:100,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            step: 1,
            animate: "slow",
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
            }
}
);

$( "#slider-value" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );


$("button").click( function(){
    $("#slider").slider('value', 150);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution was to initialize the slider with animate set to True.

Answer (score 0):

Use [animate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-animate) along with [value](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#method-value) method

Something like this should do

```
var slider = $(".slider").slider({
    value: 50,
    animate: true
});

$('#animate').click(function(){
    slider.slider('value', //required value);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/VbM9g/1/)

Hope this helps