# Moving a jquery slider slowly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

I have a slider which I want to move when I arrive at a certain div.  When it does, I want to have the slider move down while performing the interaction it is meant to.

http://jsfiddle.net/7gk2C/

This is the example, the problem being that the call `$("#secrets-slider").slider("value", $("#secrets-slider").slider("option", "min") );` does indeed move the slider,  but it does it instantly, and it doesn't do what the slider should do(move the div).

Would I need to call `$( "#magic" ).css('top', ui.value + 'px');` after it, or is there another way?  And is there an easy way to do this slowly with a variable speed?

---

For the benefit of all.  The solution I found to work seems to be...

http://jsfiddle.net/7gk2C/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`animate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-animate) option

```
$( "#secrets-slider" ).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    value: 10,
    animate: "slow",
    slide: function( event, ui ) { 
        $( "#magic" ).css('top', ui.value + 'px');
    }
});
```

For the `div` not moving, see [`slide(event, ui)`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)

> Triggered on every mouse move during slide.

So, it seems this event will not fire when the slider is set programmatically.

Comment: This indeed solves 50%.  It now moves slowly.  http://jsfiddle.net/7gk2C/2/ But how do I get it to move the div as it does so?  Or should I just match the animation manually?

Comment: Indeed...see update http://jsfiddle.net/7gk2C/3/ for working.  This seems to achieve what I want.  Don't know if it's the right way though.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-initializing the slider with the `.slider()` call, that's why the events are not triggered (technically it's not being moved).

Update:

Here is the answer from a similar question here on SO ([jQuery-ui slider animation when setting value programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608314/jquery-ui-slider-animation-when-setting-value-programmatically)), [there's also a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exXLV/8/) but this is the relevant code:

```
$("#slider").slider({
        value:100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 1,
        animate: "slow",
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
        }
});

$( "#slider-value" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );

$("button").click( function(){
    $("#slider").slider('value', 150);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [$.animate()](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/animate/&ei=Fz8UUaDEMJGyiQfA_4DYDA&usg=AFQjCNEbtYj_CVrTF4Rx7m_-wysrfpbSQw&sig2=DZAZD6inrvtCDYmJ5tVdtw&bvm=bv.42080656,d.aGc)

This will allow you to animate the slider to the position you wish and you can set a time length in milliseconds.

additionally, I think the reason that the Trigger is not moving the div is that you are not interacting with the slide control within the slider object.